# MYSQL Multiple Column SUM

Tags: mysql

I have this query below:

```
SELECT a.`reg_no`, b.`personnel_name`,

  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 1, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Jan',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 2, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Feb',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 3, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Mar',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 4, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Apr',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 5, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'May',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 6, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Jun',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 7, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Jul',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 8, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Aug',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 9, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Sept',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 10, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Oct',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 11, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Nov',
  SUM(IF(month(a.`start_time`) = 12, ROUND(a.`act_hours`),0)) as 'Dec',

  SUM('Jan' + 'Feb' + 'Mar' + 'Apr' + 'May' + 'Jun' + 'Jul' + 'Aug' + 'Sept' + 'Oct' + 'Nov' + 'Dec') / 12 as 'AVG',
  a.`status_working`

 FROM `daily_activity_control_card-man` AS a LEFT JOIN `personnel_master_data` AS b
ON a.`reg_no` = b.`reg_no` WHERE a.`status_working` = 'normal' AND YEAR(a.`start_time`) = '$_GET[df]'
GROUP BY `reg_no`
```

I need to get AVG result at the end of the column, from the query above, what I get is 0. All rows has 0 values on AVG column.
Can anybody help me with this?

I've done some searching on Google but get no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: push this in the `temp` table and get `sum` at the top

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in your application code (php in this instance).

Comment: My php code is just using mysql_fetch_array, so I don't think showing my php code is necessary. All calculation should be done in mysql side.